# Can I insert values into vector of pointers using insert function?

Tags: c++, vector

Suppose `Foo` is any class.

```
Foo f[5];

std::vector<Foo*> v;
```

I can insert the elements into vector of pointers using a for loop statement:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    v.push_back(&f[i]);
```

Is it possible to insert them using `std::vector::insert()` function and why not? I have tried several times it failed something like this:

```
v.insert(v.end(), &f[0], &f[5]); // error
```

Comment: Of course it is possible, you are probably just using `insert()` incorrectly. For example, `v.insert(v.end(), &f[i]);` is exactly equivalent to your line using `push_back()`. Show us some of your attempts.

Comment: Know that if `f` falls out of scope before `v` (in your case it won't) you will end up in trouble with dangling references.

Comment: @cdhowie: I'm trying to insert the whole array using one insert function call.

Comment: Did you mean to use `v.insert(v.end(), &f[0], &f[4]);`

Comment: @RSahu I think you mean `v.insert(v.end(), &f[0], &f[5]);`. The inserted range is [first, last) and not [first, last]. But this won't work anyway, because `*&f[0]` is a `Foo` and not a `Foo*`.

Comment: @cdhowie, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean, with a single call to `insert`, then no - that can copy a range, performing type conversions if needed, but can't apply arbitrary transformations like taking the address of each element.

You could use `std::transform`:

```
std::transform(std::begin(f), std::end(f),
               std::back_inserter(v),
               [](Foo & f) {return &f;});
```

although that's probably less clear than a simple loop, especially if you use new-style syntax

```
for (Foo & foo : f) {
    v.push_back(&foo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use insert also. But there are few differences between these two operations:-

push_back puts a new element at the end of the vector and insert allows you to select position. This impacts the performance. insert forces to move all elements after the selected position of a new element. You simply have to make a place for it. This is why insert might often be less efficient than push_back.

Comment: Well, and that `insert()` accepts an iterator before which the new item is placed. That's kind of the whole point of `insert()` -- being able to choose the location where the new item goes.